# How to align paragraphs horizontally in separate divs/spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs (that I've placed side by side) that contain paragraphs (about 5 in each). I'd like for the paragraphs to be aligned horizontally side by side. What I mean is I'd want paragraph 2 in the first div to begin at the same line as paragraph 2 in the second div (and same for all other paragraphs). I tried using jquery ui's position function as I'm already using it's slider on my project as well (https://jqueryui.com/position/) but when one of my paragraphs was too long and was not displaying in the window screen it didn't align it properly with its corresponding paragraph. Here is my html (by the way, I would like to avoid using a table because I have to replace my paragraphs later on periodically and it would be difficult change the text via my .js file if it's broken up too much):

```
<div id="container">
<div id="column-1">
 <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 3</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 4</p>
</div>
<div id="column-2">
 <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 3</p>
 <p>PARAGRAPH 4</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, the paragraphs in the divs are of varying lengths, that's really where my same-line alignment issue originates from.

Comment: You could always use a layout manager like Bootstrap. This makes it easy to make columns and rows. Something to consider if nobody has a working solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you expand on: `I would like to avoid using a table because I have to replace my paragraphs later on periodically and it would be difficult change the text via my .js file if it's broken up too much`? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @ajax992 thanks for  the suggestion! I'll look into it.

Comment: So you want to put two of paragraph 1 on the first row, two of paragraph 2 on the second row and so on?

Comment: @Pat Hi Pat, it's a bit of a long explanation. My project involves replacing the paragraphs in both the divs depending on the option a user selects on my slider (which I'm doing in the separate javascript file). If I put each paragraph in a table cell then it will take longer when I have to replace it in the javascript file. I have a feeling there's a more efficient solution I could find haha.

Comment: @JulySFX Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Noot Layoutit.com is a pretty good interactive builder for bootstrap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worth restructuring your HTML to get the same effect. I've done this below, and, as an added aid, provided JavaScript examples of how to access the paragraphs in a fashion that you may require.

With this setup, if paragraph 1 in column 1 were to be longer than paragraph 1 in column 2, column 2 would be resized to the appropriate size due to the enlarging of the parent row div.

Some CSS

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#container .row {
    /* Access rows */
}
#container .row .col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
/* Equivalent of #column-1*/
#container .row .col.column-1 {

}
/* Equivalent of #column-2 */
#container .row .col.column-2 {

}
```

And the HTML.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col column-1">PARAGRAPH 1</p>
        <p class="col column-2">PARAGRAPH 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col column-1">PARAGRAPH 2</p>
        <p class="col column-2">PARAGRAPH 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col column-1">PARAGRAPH 3</p>
        <p class="col column-2">PARAGRAPH 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col column-1">PARAGRAPH 4</p>
        <p class="col column-2">PARAGRAPH 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to select the equivalent of a specific column and sub paragraph, the javascript would look like this:

```
// Equivalent to Selecting #column-1
var col1 = document.querySelectorAll(".column-1");

// Equivalent to Selecting a Specific Paragraph
var col1_par1 = document.querySelector(".row:nth-child(1) .column-1"),
    col1_par2 = document.querySelector(".row:nth-child(2) .column-1");

// Make Text of Paragraph 3 in Column 1 red
document.querySelector(".row:nth-child(3) .column-1").style.setProperty("color", "red")
```

Comment: I've been searching like crazy for a way to solve this without putting paragraphs that I want in different columns into the same container (ie. both the 'paragraph 3' in the same div) but I will go with your answer if that's really not possible.

Comment: The extra div's aren't strictly necessary, but illustrated an established data flow hierarchy / model: row > column > cell (in this case, the paragraph). I've removed the column divs, perhaps now the answer is a bit closer to what your looking for? @Noot

Comment: Oh I see, that does simplify it more. Thank you @Greenstick.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work when the paragraphs are of varying length. I tried playing around with the code but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: I was able to get this layout working but using some flex styling!

Comment: Now I understand! If flex box works, that's great, though browser compatibility may be something to look into: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Also, there's a JavaScript library that's been developed for exactly this, called Isotope: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope

Answer (score 1):

Does your HTML code have to be exactly the same and you just want to achieve it with css/javascript or can we just change HTML a little bit like below?

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-1">
    <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-3">
    <p>PARAGRAPH 3</p>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-4">
    <p>PARAGRAPH 4</p>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I was not able to get your code working for longer paragraphs however. But I will look into that. Also to answer your question, I would like to keep my code moreso the same or at least keep all the paragraphs of column 1 in one main container and all the paragraphs of column 2 in another main container.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution w/Fiddle:

```
    <div id='holder'>
      <div id='one'>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
      </div>

      <div id='two'>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Fooo fooo foooo lorem lorem lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>

#holder {
  overflow: none;
}

#one{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#two{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

essentially im just using css w/ inline block on each element and hiding overflow using scroll for y axis. pretty straightforward.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas9114/xL73hqr2/13/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited the Fiddle a bit and I think this won't align paragraphs when they are of differing lengths in the two divs.

Comment: nice catch, im gonna look into it and mess around a bit

Answer (score 0):

I tried something with Javascript and it seems to do what you want, i mean almost (not fully responsive). However, i leave you this solution that can be interesting. It's based on DOM and nodes. You have to retrieve element nodes like p, children of column1 and column2 and compare them.
If you ask for all the children of column1 for exemple, you will grab p tags and text nodes, because p is a node which contain another node, a text node. What is interesting you here is the height of p elements.
So i grabbed all the children nodes from column1 and 2 and putted all the p elements in separate arrays, according the columns.

For finishing, in a for-loop, i compare the p elements of each array. For exemple if the height of paragraph2 in a column1 is gratter than paragraph2 in column2, then height of paragraph2 in column2 will be equal to paragraph2 in column1.

// JS :

```
var col1 = document.getElementById('column_1');
var col1Children = col1.childNodes;

var col2 = document.getElementById('column_2');
var col2Children = col2.childNodes;

var col1Child_p = [];
var col2Child_p = [];
var col1ChildTextNode = [];
var col2ChildTextNode = [];

col1.classList.add('contentM'); 
col2.classList.add('contentM');

for(var a = 0; a < col1Children.length; a++){
 if(col1Children[a].nodeType === 1){ // if child is an element node (like p)
    col1Child_p.push(col1Children[a]); //receipt element node (p)
 } else {
    col1ChildTextNode.push(col1Children[a]); // receipt text node (#text)
 }
}

for(var b = 0; b < col2Children.length; b++){
 if(col2Children[b].nodeType === 1){
  col2Child_p.push(col2Children[b]);
 } else{
  col1ChildTextNode.push(col2Children[b]); 
 }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 var col1ChildHeight = col1Child_p[i].clientHeight;
 var col2ChildHeight = col2Child_p[i].clientHeight;

if (col1Child_p[i].clientHeight > col2Child_p[i].clientHeight) {
   col2Child_p[i].style.height = col1ChildHeight + 'px';
 } else if (col1Child_p[i].clientHeight < col2Child_p[i].clientHeight{
   col1Child_p[i].style.height = col2ChildHeight + 'px';
 } else {
   console.log('not working - already the same height');
 }
}
```

// CSS :

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}

p {
 height: auto;
}

#container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#column_1 {
 background-color: orange;
}

#column_2 {
 background-color: red;
}

#column_1 p,
#column_2 p {
 background-color: pink;
}

section {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
}

.contentM {
 width: 47.389558232932%; /* 472 / 996 */
 margin: 0 1.305220883534%; /* 13 / 996 */
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}


/* under a screen size of 640 px, a css rule overwrite the javascript calculation : */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 .container {
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 13px;
 }
 .contentL,
 .contentM,
 .contentS {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 0 13px 0 !important;
 }
 p {
  height: auto !important;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
   width: 90%;
  }
}
```

/////////////

**Another solution** is using flexbox. It's probably a better solution because maintaining the code is more clean and less confusing, and it's now well supported by browsers.

I had to change the structure of you HTML doc to achieve it.

// HTML :

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <section>
   <article id="column" class="contentM"> 
    <div>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 1 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 1 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 2 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena. It applies mathematics, physics, and chemistry, in an effort to explain the origin of those objects and phenomena and their evolution.</p>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 2 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 3 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>  
     <p>PARAGRAPH 2 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 4 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena</p>
     <p>PARAGRAPH 4 : Astronomy (from Greek: αστρονομία) is a natural science that studies celestial objects and phenomena.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

// CSS :

```
p {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 5px 5px;
 background-color: orange;
}

container {
 width: 80%;
}

section {
 width: 100%;
}

article {
 margin: 5px 5px;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}

.contentM {
 width: 48%;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
}
```

// JS :

```
var col = document.getElementById('column');
var rowDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#column > div');

for(var i = 0; i < rowDiv.length; i++){
 rowDiv[i].classList.add('row');
}
```

////////

By the wait, @Noot , you said that you was able to achieve that with flex. Is it without changing the structure of you HTML document? Can you share your result?